# Having problems getting Javascript to work on SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I was looking for help last week to get a simple javascript code made for SharePoint 2007 working for SharePoint 2010 and didn't really get a clear answer that i could use where i work unfortunately so i decided to try to just make my own. It's suppossed to be an Auction List and have a countdown in the "Time Left" field till the item expires, but i can't figure out what's wrong. I am very unfamiliar with javascript and sharepoint but i am an experienced programmer. Can anyone help with this? Here's the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var list = lists.getById(listId);
var item = getItemByName("End Date");
var end = Date.parse(item.text())/1000;
var todayNow = new Date();
todayNow = Date.parse(today)/1000;
var result = (end-todayNow);
var item2 = getItemByName("Time Left");
item2.text(result);
</script>
```

The End Date is a field that will probably be hidden, but just used as a placeholder to find the difference from now till the item expires.

Thanks guys for any responses.

Comment: One suggestion that I have, but not necessarily related to your issue, is use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded( function(){...}, "SP.js");` also, could you provide any error output from a debug console (F12 in IE)?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the root cause, but in your code snippet you did not include the `</script>` tag. Also, if you are using any other JavaScript libraries (I'm not sure if you are, I'm still a bit green) be sure to include them in the header.

You can close the code correctly in the following manner:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var list = lists.getById(listId);
    var item = getItemByName("End Date");
    var end = Date.parse(item.text())/1000;
    var todayNow = new Date();
    todayNow = Date.parse(today)/1000;
    var result = (end-todayNow);
    var item2 = getItemByName("Time Left");
    item2.text(result);  
</script>
```

As a sidenote, to import any additional libraries simply lead your `<script type="text/javascript">` with additional library calls. They look like this:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Simply place one of those in front of your script body for each library you want to call.

Comment: As a note about using the CDN: http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/

Comment: Didn't see closing script tags when I viewed the response! Sorry if the response wasn't the correct answer.

Comment: @Robert Kaucher Wasn't aware of that regarding the CDN. Thank you for the info. Was using the google API as an example but I'll change it up. Thanks!

Comment: A lot of people are not aware of it. I had not considered it until I read that article. I figure the more people who know, the better!

Answer (score 0):

One useful technique for debugging javascript is to utilize the javascript console (F12 in IE, then click the 'Console' tab option).  This is a live javascript [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) environment that you can use to run your statements one-by-one in the context of the current page.  After each statement, you can inspect the variable(s) values so you better understand what each line is accomplishing.